# addObject() function is not working with .docx file in php

Tags: php, phpword

I am trying to attach(embedding) a .docx file to word document using phpword addObject() function, it's attaching file but while clicking on attached file it's not opening. If i do it for .doc file it's opening the attached file. I am using phpword library.

```
<?php
require_once '../PHPWord.php';

// New Word Document
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

// New portrait section
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();

// Add text elements
$section->addText('You can open this OLE object by double clicking on the icon:');
$section->addTextBreak(2);

// Add object
$section->addObject('Test.docx');
//if i use $section->addObject('Test.doc'); it's opening attached file. here Test.doc is word97-2003 format.
// Save File
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('Object.docx');
?>
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: Sorry, added code now.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues were already logged for this, but no solution proposed for the issue yet :-(

[addObject() function is not working with .docx file, it's working with .doc(word97-2003) file](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1080)

[Add Object Issue](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1048)

[Unable to open embedded object](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/502)